# What could cause AF_NETLINK socket transactions to take many seconds?

Tags: kernel, socket, netlink

## My problem

`AF_NETLINK` queries to the kernel intermittently take many seconds before being answered, for example in this `strace` trace:

```
10:42:38.864353 socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 3
10:42:38.864377 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
10:42:38.864399 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
10:42:38.864418 setsockopt(3, SOL_NETLINK, NETLINK_EXT_ACK, [1], 4) = 0
10:42:38.864436 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
10:42:38.864459 getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=16296, nl_groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
10:42:38.864491 sendto(3, {{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1588581759, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 1}}, 40, 0, NULL, 0) = 40
10:42:51.894848 recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 2608
```

## Background

I noticed that, every now and then, software would hang while trying to resolve an IP address. Mainly browsers, but also new `ssh`s or anything else that needs DNS.

Using Wireshark I was able to check that the hang occurred before a DNS query packet ever gets sent to the name server, so it's not a lagging nameserver by itself.

Tracing a few relevant processes showed that, every now and then, the process would read `/etc/resolv.conf` first, which has IPV6 addresses:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search example.de otherexample.de
nameserver 192.168.178.1
nameserver 2a02:8070:c19e:b400:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
nameserver fd00::9a9b:cbff:xxxx:xxxx
```

then read `/etc/gai.conf` which doesn't contain anything but comments, and then, obviously, get the list of interfaces using an AF_NETLINK socket.

Most of the time, the `sendto` and corresponding `recvmsg` are just a few milliseconds apart, but in some cases, this hangs what feels like forever.

Which made me realize that the problem isn't even DNS, and indeed, running `ip a` in a loop would, sometimes hang for several seconds as well. So I did this while stracing each ip a`and logging the output and the`strace` to two different files. This shows the problem happens about once per minute, for about 12-13 seconds:

```
10:41:58.561713 sendto(3, {{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1588581719, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 1}}, 40, 0, NULL, 0) = 40
10:41:58.561943 recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 2608

10:42:38.864491 sendto(3, {{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1588581759, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 1}}, 40, 0, NULL, 0) = 40
10:42:51.894848 recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 2608

10:43:42.269435 sendto(3, {{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1588581823, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 1}}, 40, 0, NULL, 0) = 40
10:43:54.894689 recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 2608

10:44:45.276410 sendto(3, {{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1588581886, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 1}}, 40, 0, NULL, 0) = 40
10:44:57.894722 recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 2608

10:45:48.273509 sendto(3, {{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1588581949, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 1}}, 40, 0, NULL, 0) = 40
10:46:00.894574 recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 2608
```

The first pair is an example of what happens normally; the other pairs show how the problem happens once per minute and lasts for ~ 12 seconds.

There is no significant network change during those times; here's an example of the output of `ip a` before and after one the first of those pauses:

```
Mon May  4 10:42:38 CEST 2020
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:5e:45:60:e4:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.131/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 83515sec preferred_lft 83515sec
    inet6 2a02:8070:c19e:b400:bec7:94b4:34f1:86b4/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7078sec preferred_lft 3478sec
    inet6 fe80::d27:8efd:f696:3c47/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:0e:02:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp7s0
       valid_lft 602858sec preferred_lft 602858sec
    inet6 fe80::c694:6683:6353:e9c9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlxf4f26d08d54e: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:f2:6d:08:d5:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Mon May  4 10:42:52 CEST 2020
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:5e:45:60:e4:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.131/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 83514sec preferred_lft 83514sec
    inet6 2a02:8070:c19e:b400:bec7:94b4:34f1:86b4/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7077sec preferred_lft 3477sec
    inet6 fe80::d27:8efd:f696:3c47/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:ab:d5:0e:02:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp7s0
       valid_lft 602857sec preferred_lft 602857sec
    inet6 fe80::c694:6683:6353:e9c9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlxf4f26d08d54e: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:f2:6d:08:d5:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

## The question

What could cause the kernel to delay replies to `AF_NETLINK`/`RTM_GETLINK` socket calls for several seconds, once per minute?

As far as I know, those calls are handled by the kernel directly, not by some other process (that I could `strace` for a timeout). Is this correct?

If so, what could make the kernel block on those requests, again and again? How could one debug that?

Comment: Since you can reproduce it with the strace+ip loop (if you share it we could test it too) I would first bring down evertyhing but `lo` and see if it still happens. If it does not, bringing up the other devices one by one and retesting might tell us more about the problem.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Thanks for your comment; removing the external USB WIFI adapter fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment of Eduardo Trápani, I was able to solve the problem.

As soon as I removed the USB WIFI adapter, which provided the `wlxf4f26d08d54e` interface in the above `ip a` output, the problem went away.

The exact specification of that device, according to `lsusb`, is

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

Interestingly, there are no entries at all about that device in `/var/log/syslog`, except that it was recognized at boot and I unplugged it; so I don't think it had a faulty connection or anything similar.

According to https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:0bda-8179, this driver has been in the kernel since version 3.12, and it works almost everywhere, so I don't really know what my specific problem was.

Glad it's solved now, however.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Your question was very well done and you had really dwelved into the problem from many angles. You deserved it.